# nginx:howto redirect 2 links to same path

Tags: nginx

I need redirect 2 link to same folder, ex.

www.domain.com ---> /path/to/files

www.domain.com/foo ---> /path/to/files

I have tried with "location" but don't work:

```
server {

listen 81;
server_name domain.com;
index index.php index.html;
root /path/to/files;
location /foo {
root /path/to/files;
index index.html;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
location /foo {
    alias /path/to/files;
}
```

or

```
location /foo/ {
    alias /path/to/files/;
}
```

Be careful with trailing slashes.

See http://nginx.org/r/alias for details.

Comment: Thanks, it work's! But work only with trailing slash, whitout in any configuration i have 404 not found error, is possible to set to work, with and whitout "/" at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a rewrite:

```
location /foo {
    root /path/to/files;
    index index.html;
    rewrite ^/foo(/.*|)$ $1 break;
}
```